# Multiple Variable Limit.x, y tending to 1

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I have a multi-variable limit issue that I have no idea how to do.

$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)} \frac{(x-1)^{4/3}-(y-1)^{4/3}}{(x-1)^{2/3}+(y-1)^{2/3}} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle(x-1)^{4/3}-(y-1)^{4/3}=\bigl((x-1)^{2/3}+(y-1)^{2/3}\bigr)\times\bigl((x-1)^{2/3}-(y-1)^{2/3}\bigr)$,

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry for my inattention.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Apply

$$a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$$

where $a=(x-1)^{2/3}$ and $b=(y-1)^{2/3}$. This gives you

$$\frac{a^2-b^2}{a+b}$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

To simplify let:

- $ u=(x-1)^{2/3}$
- $ v=(y-1)^{2/3}$

then

$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)} \frac{(x-1)^{4/3}-(y-1)^{4/3}}{(x-1)^{2/3}+(y-1)^{2/3}} = \lim_{(u,v)\to(0,0)} \frac{u^2-v^2}{u+v} $$

Comment: Thank you so much!